# jQuery get all elements beneath specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all script elements that start with same id prefix beneath specific div. Let say i have html code like:

```
<div id="row-1">
    <script id="fix-1"></script>
</div>
<div id="row-2">
    <script id="fix-2"></script>
</div>
<div id="row-3">
    <script id="fix-3"></script>
</div>
<div id="row-4">
    <script id="fix-4"></script>
</div>
```

So for example i want to get all script elements beneath div with id #row-2. It should return fix-3 and fix-4.

Comment: What have you tried? And what exactly does _"element is not always on same position inside div"_ mean? And why do your divs contains script elements that are closed with div tags?

Comment: Your HTML is really broken....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to get all the siblings after the element.

```js
var elems = $("#row-2").nextAll();
elems.css("background-color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="row-1">
    <div id="fix-1">X</div>
</div>
<div id="row-2">
    <div id="fix-2">X</div>
</div>
<div id="row-3">
    <div id="fix-3">X</div>
</div>
<div id="row-4">
    <div id="fix-4">X</div>
</div>
```

So you want the elements combine it with next and find.

```
$("#row-2").nextAll().find("script")
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer...but how can we do it in pure javascript

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try as:

```
$("#row-2 ~ div").find("script")
```

Comment: I didn't get your question earlier so couldn't write right statement.
Can you please check now if you want this?

Comment: @j08681 Can you explain why. It gives me same result like `$("#row-2").nextAll().find("script")`

Comment: @tuna: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Comment: @tuna...$("#row-2 ~ div") it is trying to find all divs which comes after div(row-2) and finds script within it...so that's the result as similar to the nextAll